# Märklin Model Railway Control: ComPort - read dumped bytes from track detection modules / Win Power Shell

Tags: com-port

I would like to test some functions of my Märklin Digital model railway system. Basically it consists of a (Märklin) Central Unit and an (Märklin) Interface. This is the minimum configuration to send system commands from PC via ComPort to the Interface to set solenoids or control trains. Also information can be sent back from track detection modules via Interface ComPort to the PC. In this case two bytes are sent back. For this case an example in Basic is given in the instructions and I tried to translate it to Win Power Shell.

Basic example:

```
10 OPEN "COM1:2400,N,8,2"FOR OUTPUT AS #1
20 OPEN "COM1:2400,N,8,2"FOR INPUT AS #2
10 OPEN "COM1:2400,N,8,2"FOR OUTPUT AS #1
20 OPEN "COM1:2400,N,8,2"FOR INPUT AS #2
30 PRINT #1,CHR$(193);:a$=INPUT$(2,#2)
30 PRINT #1,CHR$(193);:a$=INPUT$(2,#2)
40 contact=ASC(LEFT$(a$,1)):PRINT contact
50 contact2=ASC(RIGHT$(a$,1)):PRINT contact2
```

My "translation":

`$connectionproxy = new-object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort com1`

`$connectionproxy.BaudRate = 2400`

`$connectionproxy.stopbits = "two"`

`$connectionproxy.DataBits = 8`

`$connectionproxy.Parity = "None"`

`$connectionproxy.open()`

`do { $connectionproxy.write([char]([int]193)) $ShowBytes = $connectionproxy.ReadLine() Write-Host $ShowBytes } while($connectionproxy.IsOpen)`

Problem: I am not able to safe in a file / show data which has been requested from the detection modules.

What is wrong / missing in my translation?

Answer (score 0):

With some serious support (brother and a good friend) I can now deliver the requested functions. All functions have been tested with Märklin 6020/ 6023/6050/6088.

1.) "Windows 7 Power Shell", but without functionality of the Rückmeldemodul S88 (6088):

```
#---init command sets---
$commandset = @()

#---init connection---
$connectionproxy = new-object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort com1
$connectionproxy.BaudRate = 2400
$connectionproxy.stopbits = "two"
$connectionproxy.DataBits = 8
$connectionproxy.Parity = "None"

do {
$userimput = Read-Host -Prompt "Numbers seperated by space"
$currentcommand = $userimput.split(" ")
$connectionproxy.open()
for ($i=0;$i -lt $currentcommand.length;$i++) {
$connectionproxy.write([char]([int]$currentcommand[$i]))
start-sleep -milliseconds 10
}

$connectionproxy.close()

}while($true)
```

2.) "Ruby On Rails" for usage of Rückmeldemodul S88 (6088). This program reads the bytes sent back by S88 and shows its pin assignment:

```
require 'rubyserial'
class Integer
 def to_bin(width)
 '%0*b' % [width, self]
 end
end

puts "open serial port..."
serialport = Serial.new "COM1", 2400, 8, :none, 2
puts serialport.inspect
puts "Reset command for S88:"
bytes_written = serialport.write 192.chr
puts bytes_written.to_s + " bytes written"

sleep(0.1)

puts "Read first S88:"
bytes_written = serialport.write 193.chr
puts bytes_written.to_s + " bytes written"

sleep(0.1)

b1 = serialport.getbyte.inspect
puts "Byte 1: " + b1 + " (" + b1.to_i.to_bin(8) + ")"
b2 = serialport.getbyte.inspect
puts "Byte 2: " + b2 + " (" + b2.to_i.to_bin(8) + ")"
```

Issue 1: Windows Power Shell is not able to recover any bytes upon request. If anyone knows a good solution, you are welcome to share it.
Issue 2: The Rückmeldemodul 6088 and its cable to the central station or interface have to be placed away from the rails, because of inteferences with the signals. (Shielding of the sixcore cable is absolutely miserable.)